# website content to appear in header but load last

Tags: css, layout, seo

Im trying to clean up my header so that it contains only what is deemed important for seo. However, I have a number of items (adverts, contact info) I would like to display in the header region but load at the very end of the page.

Perhaps Im missing something obvious in my search queries but I could not find an answer, which is strange cause this seems like something that would be common. What am I missing?

I presume be the best way to do this (css or javascript...or)?

Comment: I'm confused, if you want to display something at the top of the page, you need some kind of hook to put it there. When you say `but load at the very end of the page` I assume you are referring to timing, not physical location.

Comment: Well here is a simple example. The wordpress admin bar appears at the very top of the page (front end when logged in as admin) but when you view the page source code you can see its loads last, ie at the very bottom of the generated code. This is what Im trying to achieve for these adverts and other 'unnecessary' things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your head tag and header tag are not the same thing. All of your SEO stuff should go in your head tag. You adverts and contact info should go in your header tag.